# Как настроить SMTP сервер для массовой рассылки писем?

Tags: email, smtp, mail.ru, gmail

Есть компания, и у нее большое количество подписчиков. Нужно добиться того, чтобы как можно меньше писем попадало в спам на таких сервисах как *gmail.com*, *mail.ru*, *yandex mail*.

На сервере установлен *postfix*, *opendkim*, *spf*. Указаны все записи в *DNS* (PTR, SPF, DKIM, DMARC, ADSP). В письмах стоит ссылка для отписки.

Но это не помогает: письма всё равно попадают в спам (хотя в спам-базах всё чисто).

Пожалуйста, помогите решением по борьбе с фильтрами. Каким образом можно добиться рассылки 100 000 писем прямым подписчикам?

Поделитесь информацией, может, ссылками на полезную информацию.

Есть способы обойтись без транзакционных *email*?

Или, может, как-то возможно сделать своё решение с помощью пула *IP*-адресов?

Comment: Борьба со спам-фильтрами? Очень надеюсь, что решения нет (а спамеры будут гореть в аду). Пусть юзеры добавят вас в белый список (если они и правда _хотят_ получать вашу рассылку). А если не хотят, любое решение по насильному проталкиванию им почты ничем не отличается от спама.

Comment: Не нужно придумывать велосипед, все ваши проблемы решит сервис [mailgun.com](http://www.mailgun.com/). До 10 000 писем в месяц бесплатно. Можно привязать свой домен и настроить DKIM. Пользуюсь им уже давно, осуществляю небольшую рассылку разнообразных уведомлений. Очень доволен, чего и вам желаю.

Answer (score 10):

спамерам *google*-овских почтовых серверов (к которым вы, конечно, не имеете никакого отношения, ни-ни) для начала стоит ознакомиться с документом [Bulk Senders Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en).

аналогично для *mail.ru*: [Технические и административные требования для отправки электронных сообщений на Mail.Ru](http://help.mail.ru/mail-help/rules/technical).

аналогично для *yandex.ru*: [Требования Яндекса к честным рассылкам](https://yandex.ru/support/mail/spam/honest-mailers.xml).

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Но тут действительно не рассматривается спам, всё по человеческию