# google отправляет первое письмо в spam

Tags: email, gmail, спам

Отправляю письмо с подтверждением о регистрации, на `@gmail.com`.
Первое письмо всегда попадает в спам. Хеш-сумма тела отличается, почтовый ящик использую свой личный, понятно что с него не производилось никаких рассылок. Письма отправляю через `smtp.gmail.com`
Проект находится на стадии разработки, так что реальных пользователей нет - письма положить в спам кроме меня никто не мог бы. Информации о том как лечится и из-за чего такое случается не нашел.

Если отметить письма как не **спам** они начинают приходить во входящие, но первые попадают в спам.

На многих сайтах при регистрации пишут, если письмо не пришло проверьте в **спам**е

**google** подсказывает

> "Оно похоже на сообщения, которые фильтры ранее распознавали как
>   нежелательные."

Как можно исправить такое поведение?

Comment: ну возможно есть способ как это лечить а я этого просто не смог найти.

Comment: с информацией [для «рассыльщиков»](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436385/178576) вы уже ознакомились?

Comment: Вы конечно прочли то что отправляю с личного акаунта, в тестовом режиме?
да с документацией google ознакомлен. речь идет не о рассылке, а о том что первое письмо отображается в спаме

Comment: Так вам гугль же прямо пишет "Оно похоже на сообщения, которые фильтры ранее распознавали как нежелательные.". То есть или делайте письмо с содержимым не похожим на другие письма (от других отправителей подтверждений) :) Или используйте разные технологии (DKIM, SPF, DMARC) о чем гугль пишет в своей инструкции (если я его правильно понял со своим нулевыи английским).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Критерии распознавания спама у каждого сервиса свои и, например, гугл в справке опубликовал некоторые [рекомендации](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=ru), но гарантий это не дает.

1. Если отправляете как пользователь gmail, должно хватать отправки через ssl от имени авторизованного пользователя;
2. Если отправитель "чужой", то ваш отправляющий сервер и домен должны быть максимально похожими на "хороших":

   2.1. Безупречная репутация IP-адреса - никаких попаданий в DNSBL;

   2.2. Корректно настроенный SPF;

   2.3. Корректно настроенный и работающий DKIM;

   2.4. Прописанная запись PTR, крайне желательно чтобы она не была похожа на динамический адрес, то есть не содержать поддоменов типа adsl, dyn, dhcp, cable, user и т. д (лучше если у вашего IP нету PTR по-умолчанию, которые прописывают некоторые провайдеры);

   2.5. Хорошо еще если ваша сеть нигде в "агрегирующих" черных списках не прописана (типа uceprotect.net) или вообще выдана на вас или вашу организацию

Answer (score 2):

1. Пишите в поддержку google за более подробной информацией.
2. Если они не на, что страшное не ответят, скажите им что они случайно внесли вас в список спама.

Достаточно давно работаю с рассылками, очень часто непонятные проблемы. Попадаешь в спам, спрашиваешь почему, они отвечают не известно и удаляют из спам списка (правда на это чаще грешит mail.ru).