# Подтверждение регистрации по email

Tags: email, регистрация

Веб-приложение отправляет письмо для завершения регистрации (стандартная процедура как у всех). У некоторых пользователей письмо оказывается в спаме, у некоторых нет. Подскажите пожалуйста от чего это зависит и как поднять "надежность" писем, чтобы фильтры не ругались. Никакого спама или массовых рассылок, точечные письма, не так уж и часто отправляемые.

Хостинг чужой, vps.

Comment: Приложение на чужом хостинге?

Comment: Способы поднятия надёжности: заполнить все заголовки отправляемого письма. Домен и отправитель должны совпадать. Не секрет, что именно анализ письма является решающим: " при регистрации указали ваш е-майл - если это вы, то вот ссылка на подтверждение", контакты отправителя, ссылка "отписаться"..

Comment: да, хостинг чужой, vps, ip-статический, домена пока нет, точнее есть, но не настроен.

Comment: Читайте этот ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436379/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-smtp-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC#436385

Comment: SMTP свой используете?

Comment: Уже понял откуда надо начинать искать решение. Буду работать над вопросом.

Comment: @artwolf, если все получиться, оформите ответом свои решения.