# Письма стали долго доходить до адресата

Tags: linux, smtp

Нарисовалась проблемка с почтой.
Сервера mail.ru и yandex.ru при приеме писем от моего почтового сервера начали выдавать:

```
Result: delayed, Status: 4.3.2 451 Rate limit exceeded
```

В результате чего письмо доходит по 2-5 часов.
На мой взгляд это связано с тех. ограничениями рассылки писем на почты mail.ru и yandex.ru

Прошу подсказать, «как правильно рассылать письма».

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как настроить SMTP сервер для массовой рассылки писем?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436379/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-smtp-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, что-то совсем непохоже...

Comment: @Qwertiy, там ответ на последнюю фразу вопроса: «Прошу подсказать "как правильно рассылать письма"»

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но не от спама же.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в ответе приведены ссылки на рекомендации организаторам рассылок. то есть на то самое, что просит автор *этого* вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, они могут быть ему полезны. Но вопрос всё-таки другой. Думаю, хватило бы ссылке в комментарии/ответе, а как дубликат закрывать не стоит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скопировано из ответа: [Как настроить SMTP сервер для массовой рассылки писем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436385/178576):

клиентам *google*-овских почтовых серверов для начала стоит ознакомиться с документом [Bulk Senders Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en).

аналогично для *mail.ru*: [Технические и административные требования для отправки электронных сообщений на Mail.Ru](http://help.mail.ru/mail-help/rules/technical).

аналогично для *yandex.ru*: [Требования Яндекса к честным рассылкам](https://yandex.ru/support/mail/spam/honest-mailers.xml).